# ArrayList error when it comes to .add()

Tags: java, arraylist

Any help is greatly appreciated. I've been scratching my head on this, not knowing why none of my ArrayLists like to .add() anything into it. The errors are in a method called play, inside a class called SimplePoker. I'm also juggling two other classes called Decks and Card here, so I feel like my problem has to do with that but I'm not entirely sure at the moment:

```
public void play() 
{
    //Array lists
    ArrayList<Card>currentHand = new ArrayList<Card>();
    ArrayList<Decks> dealCards = new ArrayList<Decks>();

    // implement this method!
    while(balance >0){


        //Showing the balance
        balance = startingBalance;
        System.out.println("Your current balance is: " +balance);

        //Scanner asking for wager
        Scanner fromKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How much would you like to wager? ");
        bet = fromKeyboard.nextInt();

        //To play
        if(bet <= balance){
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            List<Card> discardCards;
            System.out.println("Lets play!");

            //Placing bet
            balance -= bet;

            //Distributing first 5 cards
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
                currentHand.add(dealCards.get(i));
                dealCards.remove(i);

            }

            //Discarding cards
            System.out.println("Which cards would you like to throw (Enter any of the digits: 1 2 3 4 5, respectively: ");
            while (in.hasNext()){
                discardCards.add(in);
            }

        }
        //Or not to play
        else
            System.out.println("Not a valid wager");

    }

}
```

When I run it, I get this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The method add(Card) in the type List<Card> is not applicable for the arguments (Decks)
The method add(Card) in the type List<Card> is not applicable for the arguments (Scanner)
```

Comment: `The method add(Card) in the type List<Card> is not applicable for the arguments (Scanner)`. It says that you are trying to add a `Scanner` instance to a `List<Card>`.

Comment: `dealCards` holds `Desks`, `currentHand` holds `Card`, you can't add `Desks` to a list of `Card`s...

Comment: It seems like the arraylist you created is of generic type 'Card' and you are adding object of 'Decks' class. If 'Decks' class is not a subclass of 'Card' class, JVM will through this expection. Either make your arraylist class of type 'Decks' or extends 'Decks' class with 'Card' if the design permits you

Comment: Thank you so much, it helps reading all of these comments. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your arrays have different types.

```
ArrayList<Decks> dealCards = new ArrayList<Decks>();
ArrayList<Card>currentHand = new ArrayList<Card>();
List<Card> discardCards;
```

currentHand.add(dealCards.get(i)); - you cannot add Deck object  to Card array

Also here:

```
 while (in.hasNext()){
            discardCards.add(in);
        }
```

You cannot add "in" to the list. You will need to read from "in" and conver the value to object.

Comment: I was thinking I could do it directly, but I understand, thank you. This really helped me out above all

Answer (score 1):

`dealCards.get(i)` returns a instance of `Decks`. 
So it can not be added to `currentHand` wich expected a instance of `cards`.